# Rails - AdminMailer - setting sender name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using Rails 4 to make a web app.

I have a mailer set up to send a welcome mailer to new users.

I want to change the appearance of the sender name from the email address to "Welcome to CF".

Where to I set the name of the sender?

```
class WelcomeMail < ActionMailer::Base
  self.delivery_method = :smtp
  self.smtp_settings = {
    user_name:            ENV['GPROD_WELCOME'],
    password:             ENV['GPwPROD_WELCOME'],
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'cr.com',
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }


def welcome_mail(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: user.email, from: "angus@cr.com", subject: "Welcome to Cr, #{user.first_name}")
end


end
```

When it's changed, I want angus@cr.com to appear as Welcome to CR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the value of from within your mail params:

`from: "Angus <angus@xyz.com>"`

The text before the <> will be displayed as the from name.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible keep, user.email at from ,means to the admin he can know mail was recieved from particular user

from: user.email